# How to add an image to an primefaces menubar programmatically?

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, menuitem, menubar

I have a menubar with an image and want to change this to programmatically code to make this dynamically. But, I can't get the image in.

Any advice how to add the image programmatically?

*This is my original xhtml code:*

```
<p:menubar>
    <p:menuitem>
        <p:link outcome="/index.xhmtl">
            <p:graphicImage url="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg" height="50"/>
        </p:link>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:submenu label="Routine">
        <p:menuitem value="Item 1" outcome="/routine/item1.xhtml"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Item 2" outcome="/routine/item2.xhtml"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Item 3" outcome="/routine/item3.xhtml"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Lab">
        <p:menuitem value="Item 1" outcome="/lab/item1.xhtml"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Item 2" outcome="/lab/item2.xhtml"/>
    </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

*This is my new java code:*

```
MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
DefaultMenuItem item = new DefaultMenuItem("Default");
DefaultSubMenu submenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Default");

submenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Routine");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Item 1");
item.setOutcome("/routine/item1.xhtml");
submenu.addElement(item);
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Item 2");
item.setOutcome("/routine/item2.xhtml");
submenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(submenu);
```

How do I add the image with link?
I can't git this working programmatically.

This generates a nullpointer on line: submenu.addElement

*This is how I tried to add the image:* I need help here. This does not work.

```
submenu = new DefaultSubMenu("Logo");
GraphicImage image = new GraphicImage();
image.setUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg");
image.setHeight("50");
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Logo");
submenu.addElement(item);
model.addElement(submenu);
```

Comment: You did this in your immediate previous question on your own. The only difference is that here you are doing the same through some Java code. What is need to take/consider an ugly Java code way in this case which in turn is not easily readable/maintainable?

Comment: This is indeed a lot of boiler plate code, but the menu will change on user credentials. So, this menu is highly dynamically and needs a programmatically solution.

Comment: So how do you do this? I have no idea, what is @Tiny talking about.